# Trying to adjust my VBA Macro for inserting batches of rows into an SQL Server

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have already managed to program this VBA macro which takes as an input a range within an excel sheet, iterates over its columns and rows and then inserts the values with a SQL statement into a server database. But since some files which I need to insert into the database have over 90.000 rows I need to implement a batch insert inside my for loop, so that every iteration only takes a set number of rows for the insert procedure (like for example 500 rows at a time).

Below you find the code of the Macro which works just fine with smaller datasets:

```
Function RangeToInsert(rRng As Range) As String

   Dim vaData As Variant
   Dim i As Long, j As Long
   Dim aReturn() As String
   Dim aCols() As String
   Dim aVals() As Variant

   Const sINSERT As String = "INSERT INTO dbo.ExcelTest2"
   Const sVAL As String = " VALUES "

   'Read in data
   vaData = rRng.Value

   'Create arrays
   ReDim aReturn(1 To UBound(vaData))
   ReDim aCols(1 To UBound(vaData, 2))
   ReDim aVals(1 To UBound(vaData, 2))

   'Fill column name array from first row
   For j = LBound(vaData, 2) To UBound(vaData, 2)
       aCols(j) = "[" & vaData(1, j) & "]"
   Next j

   'Go through the rest of the rows
   For i = LBound(vaData, 1) + 1 To UBound(vaData, 1)

       'Fill a temporary array
       For j = LBound(vaData, 2) To UBound(vaData, 2)
           aVals(j) = "'" & vaData(i, j) & "'":
       Next j

       'Build the string into the main array
       aReturn(i) = sINSERT & "(" & Join(aCols, ",") & ")" & sVAL & "(" & Join(aVals, ",") & ");"
   Next i

   RangeToInsert = Join(aReturn, vbNewLine)

End Function

Sub Test_Export()
   
   Dim sConnString As String
   Dim tbl As ListObject
   Dim column_count, row_count As Integer
   Dim Headers As Variant
   
   sConnString = "Provider=X;Data Source=X;Initial Catalog = X;Integrated Security=SSPI"
   Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
   Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
   conn.Open sConnString
   conn.Execute ("use Salesreport")
   conn.Execute ("truncate table dbo.ExcelTest2")
   
   conn.Execute (RangeToInsert(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AC5000")))

End Sub
```

For the batching I thought about adding an if clause along those lines:

```
If (i Mod 500) = 0 Then
                aReturn(i) = sINSERT & "(" & Join(aCols, ",") & ")" & sVAL & "(" & Join(aVals, ",") & ");"
                RangeToInsert = Join(aReturn, vbNewLine)
                RangeToInsert = RangeToInsert As String
                conn.Execute (RangeToInsert)
End If
```

But to be honest I am a little bit stuck right now on how I can actually implement this clause into the for loop while also making sure that still every row of the dataset gets inserted in the end. I would be really greatful for every hint or help.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a weird design. Maybe you need to re-think your setup. You can certainly use VBA, like you are doing, or do a bulk insert into SQL Server, from a CSV. Here's a link with some info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

There are resize functions and offset functions that you may be able to leverage, but anytime you use 'select' things are going to run slow.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/10/03/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scan-a-large-range-in-excel/

You can even save the XL file as a tab-delimited text file and do this...

```
BULK INSERT TableName
        FROM 'C:\your_file_path.txt'
            WITH
    (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
GO
```

https://dbtut.com/index.php/2019/05/13/bulk-insert-in-sql-server/

Also, Python offers an easy way to chunk data and do multiple inserts.

https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-large-datasets-in-pandas-11bdddd36f7b

Although, maybe Python is outside the realm of feasibility for you. Just offering a couple ideas here.